# Well-posedness for a wave equation with degenerate coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, pseudo-differential-operators, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and consider the following initial boundary value problem:
\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
t\partial_t(t\partial_t u)-\Delta u+Vu=0\,\quad &\text{on $(0,T)\times \Omega$},
\\
u=f\,\quad &\text{on $\Sigma=(0,T)\times \partial \Omega$,}\\
u(0,x)=\partial_t u(0,x)=0 \,\quad &\text{on $\Omega$,}
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Is there a good theory for solving these kind of problems? The issue of course is the degeneracy at $t=0$. Any answers or references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try a change of variables in time to make it a standard wave operator (unless that's where you started and were hoping changing to this form would make things easier).

Comment: That’s exactly what happened!

Comment: I apologize for the perhaps silly questions, but is $V$ a function or a constant? And if it is a function then $V=V(x)$ or $V=V(t,x)$?

Comment: sorry for not clarifying that... It is a smooth function of $t$ and $x$. But perhaps as a simpler question it can just be assumed to be zero.

Comment: After thinking for some time, the only trick I feel it would help you is to use the Mellin transform respect to the time variable $t$: $${\hat u}(s,x)=\mathscr{M}[u](s,x) =\int\limits_0^\infty t^{s-1} u(t, x) \, \mathrm{d}t. $$ Its application to your PDE transforms the modified time derivative $t \partial_t$ in the complex variable $s$, and then you possibly have only to analyze an elliptic problem with complex coefficient.